# AzureAD OIDC Implicit Flow with response_type=id_token+token fails when user not logged in

Tags: azure-active-directory, openid-connect

**The key question:**

Is it valid to expect a successful response when requesting `response_type=id_token+token` and the user is not logged in?  Or must I first get an `id_token` and then make a second request for an `access_token`?  (And thus patch angular2-oauth2-oidc.)

**Some background and expectation:**

- I have an AzureAD tenant where I have defined and enterprise application.
- That app has implicit flow enabled and the permissions for id_token and token are both enabled.
- I have defined one app-specific scope.
- The app is specific to my tenant (so not using the /common authorization endpoint).
- The user is in Azure ID and has been granted access to the app.

Note that *everything is fine given the user already has an active session* with Azure/Microsoft (e.g. they've logged in previously at login.microsoftonline.com).

The issue is when the user has no active session.  I expect Azure to log them in and then issue both an id_token and an access_token.  Is that expectation reasonable?

**Three test cases:**

When I request a id_token only the user is prompted to log in and I am issued and id_token.

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/a3fbb27a-68f7-42bf-a757-8b3849e72df5/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=2b58c4c9-22df-4e50-9abf-1d721cf694b0&response_type=id_token&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A4200&scope=openid&nonce=678910
```

When I request a token only the user is prompted to log in and I am issued an access_token.

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/a3fbb27a-68f7-42bf-a757-8b3849e72df5/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=2b58c4c9-22df-4e50-9abf-1d721cf694b0&response_type=token&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A4200&scope=api%3A%2F%2F2b58c4c9-22df-4e50-9abf-1d721cf694b0%2fdostuff&nonce=678910
```

When I request both id_token and token (request_type=id_token%20token) I get a `server_error`: 
 `error_description=AADSTS50000%3a+There+was+an+error+issuing+a+token.`

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/a3fbb27a-68f7-42bf-a757-8b3849e72df5/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=2b58c4c9-22df-4e50-9abf-1d721cf694b0&response_type=id_token%20token&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A4200&scope=openid%20api%3A%2F%2F2b58c4c9-22df-4e50-9abf-1d721cf694b0%2fdostuff&nonce=678910
```

**Additional notes:**

- The GUIDs above are fake but consistent across three samples.
- Ultimately the app is angular2+ (v6.1.10) and I am using angular2-oauth2-oidc.
- In the case of just id_token, angular2-oauth2-oidc fails to "validate tokens" and does not do a second round-trip to attain an access_token.
- In the case of just token, angular2-oauth2-oidc continually redirects back to the authorization server (presumably to get an id_token).
- In the case of id_token+token, the above error is received.
- The tests above reproduce manually/without an app/straight in the browser.
- Other posts regarding AADSTS50000 seem to be unrelated.

[Microsoft's page on the topic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-implicit-grant-flow) indicates that `id_token+token` is supported but the [sample URL](https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=6731de76-14a6-49ae-97bc-6eba6914391e&response_type=id_token&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fmyapp%2F&scope=openid&response_mode=fragment&state=12345&nonce=678910) only uses `id_token`.

Comment: That.. Sounds like a problem in AAD.

Comment: I believe the failure in angular2-oauth2-oidc is related to the inability to access the config endpoint due to CORS.  This is a known issue we're working to get fixed.  

Your scenario should work though - we're certified on that endpoint token+id_token.  Can you provide the timestamp and correlation ID included with the error? It doesn't contain any PII, but if you'd prefer you can send it to me directly at hirsin @ Microsoft.com

Comment: Thank you, Hirsch - the problem is that this doesn't work /manually/.  If I enter the id_token+token request directly in a browser then it fails.  I have also worked around CORS locally to ensure angular-oauth2-oidc an retrieve everything (e.g. the keys document).  Timestamp and Correlation are:  2019-02-04 15:22:30Z 2cba6517-5529-4e1f-8dfe-d9f26a369a7b